# How to use python virtualenv in other program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv

I need to call a python script in other programs(perl or ruby or other), but this python script needs to be run inside a virtualenv.

How to setup virtualenv in other program?

Comment: virtualenv will do it's job by running python in a virtual environment, system wide packages like ruby or perl will run in a normal way inside a sub process.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess